# Inconsistent constant pool data in classfile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, intellij-14

I am trying to use spark cassandra connector to fetch values from the table. The load() yields the IncompatibleClassChangeError. My development environment is defined as follows,
Intellij : 2019.3.2 
Scala version : 2.12.10 
Scala binary version : 2.12 
Spark version : 2.4.4 
Spark cassandra connector : 2.4.2 
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Inconsistent constant pool data in classfile for class com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/StructDef. Method 'java.lang.Object $anonfun$missingColumns$1$adapted(com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.StructDef, com.datastax.spark.connector.ColumnRef)' at index 182 is CONSTANT_MethodRef and should be CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodRef`
Which libraries creates the exception?

Comment: I suspect that it pulled cassandra connector compiled for 2.11

Comment: please add the exact maven coordinates for this dependency....

Comment: may be there are jar conflicts, when I use presto, I face the same problem,  I found out that  presto-jdbc and prestodb-jdbc are both on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue with loading data from the Cassandra version 4 by using the Spark 3.1.3 and the Scala 2.12 and the Java 17.

My issue resolved by reducing version of Java to 8.